# Getting error: cannot import name 'get_user_id' from 'superset.utils.core'

Tags: python, apache-superset

When installing on Mac and calling:

```bash
superset db upgrade
```

I'm getting an error:

```
cannot import name 'get_user_id' from 'superset.utils.core'
```

checking `core.py` indeed I cannot find such function.
Any tips please?

Comment: Did you follow the [official guide](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/)?